# Google Apps script to convert 1000s of pdfs to Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, google-docs

Can a Google Apps script be written to convert 1000s of PDFs to Google Docs?

Currently you have to open individual PDFs one-by-one "Open with Google Docs" to perform this transformation.

This is my first time working with Google Apps script (Google Doc > Tools > Script editor)

I have attempted to use https://github.com/odeke-em/drive but not having success yet.

Syncdocs https://www.syncdocs.com/forums/topic/pdf-conversion-issues#post-10464 is paid 3rd party tool that might work, but looking to do this for free if possible.

http://patt0.blogspot.com/2014/08/continuous-batch-library-update-for.html has some ideas but I have not been able to understand how to implement them.

keep getting an error

> Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")Dismiss"

when entering any code

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details about your attempt your of using Google Apps ScrIpt,If you got an error message , add the textual error message

Comment: Hi sirgeo, Google Apps Script is a _JavaScript_ implementation, so you can't write Bash scripts here.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script can't run code like

```
drive init ~/gdrive
cd ~/gdrive
```

Google Apps Script only can run JavaScript code with some limitations, like it doesn't  support by default `let` statements, `promises` among other.

Note: Converting files from PDF to Google Documents isn't an straightforward tasks because not all the PDF features could be converted

From [Convert PDF to Doc with Google Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36053198/1595451)

> ```
> function pdfToDoc() {  
>   var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById('0B3m2D6239t6aWHo5TVpyYzhxV1U').getBlob();  
>   var resource = {
>     title: fileBlob.getName(),
>     mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
>   };
>   var options = {
>     ocr: true
>   };
>   var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
>   Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);  
> }
> ```
>
> Add Drive API to google apps script project
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services
>
> You can see you pdf file id on google drive when you download it
>   [http://i.imgur.com/3pYvwjx.png](https://i.imgur.com/3pYvwjx.png)

NOTE: I didn't tested the above code yet.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Related

- [Process all files in Google Drives into Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95506/88163)
- [Can I convert a MS Word document to a Google Document format using GAS?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56937/88163)
- [Is it possible for a Google App Script to convert a file in the cloud?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125885/88163) (No answers at this time)

Comment: getting an error _"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss"_ https://i.imgur.com/YhVxiy4.png

Comment: @sirgeo I suggest you to post a new question including more details that describe how you adapted the to code including how do you get the file ID, if you are the owner of if it was shared with you, etc.

Comment: @ Rubén i copy / pasted that censored portion from the url of my google drive guessing that was the unique key required in that part of the script... was that not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution with odeke-em's `drive` tool you mentioned.

Keep in mind that this tool is a [CLI (Command Line Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) tool and has no connection with `Google Apps Script`. This tool also will probably not work on `Windows`.

**Get OAuth2 Credentials**

```
drive init ~/gdrive
cd ~/gdrive
```

`drive init` will give you a link with the `OAuth2` authorization code. Enter the authorization code in the prompt.

Create a folder inside the gdrive folder and put your pdf files in this folder.

Execute `drive push -convert YourFolderName`

This will recursively go through the folder and convert every file to its native Google Docs format.

source: https://github.com/odeke-em/drive

Comment: keep getting an error "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")Dismiss"

Comment: `drive` is a `cli` (Command Line Interface) tool. `drive` should be executed inside a terminal. `drive` has no connection with `google apps script`. Like @Rubén said, you can only use `Javascript` with `Google Apps Script`.

Comment: in Windows 7 "Windows Command Processor" neither **drive init ~/gdrive
cd ~/gdrive** iare recognized... is odeke-em's tool not Windows-friendly or am i missing something else?

Comment: You need to install the tool first. The installation instruction are described on the github page you linked, but the github page says that it probably will not work on `Windows`.

Comment: It does appear to be built for Linux users.... It seems Google purposefully designed G Drive to not allow batch processing their "Open in Google Docs" OCR tool without an enormous amount of work-around, like odeke-em's tool..... the question is why?

Comment: https://ctrlq.org/code/20082-google-docs-ocr has a GAS solution, but having issues with it recognizing G Drive folder paths https://i.imgur.com/fqKfg3B.png

Answer (score 0):

I got something to work here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687444/batch-convert-jpg-to-google-docs

Batch convert PDF to Google Docs

SOURCE AND DESTIN: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/123456789

```
Function convertPDFtoGoogleDocs() {
var srcfolderId = "123456789"; // <--- Please input folder ID.
var dstfolderId = srcfolderId; // <--- If you want to change the destination folder, please modify this.
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF); // Modified
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstfolderId}]},     (),     {ocr: true}); // Modified
}
}
```

i needed to also use the following link to solve another error that initially pops up using this script:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838960/referenceerror-drive-is-not-defined-line-16-file-code-in-google-app-scr